# Are my questions acceptable here

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My questions are about some concepts of programming language. I was wondering if such questions are unacceptable here?

For example,

- One is "[Understand foreign function
  interface (FFI) and language
  binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440968/understand-foreign-function-interface-ffi-and-language-binding)"
- Another is "[Is there some nice
  description about language
  features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439060/is-there-some-nice-description-about-language-features)"?

One has been flagged as off-topic on Stack-overflow. This and the rate of reply both make me come here to ask if there may be a chance for match.

If they are completely unacceptable here as well, do you happen to know some places where I can ask these questions or some suggestion on improving my questions?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that they do not fit within the scope of the site. The first is purely about implementation issues. The second, as it is phrased, asks for a purely descriptive account of the language features, and thus does not fall within the scope of theoretical computer science.

Possible ways of rephrasing your questions so that they would fall within the scope of this site include:

- Is there any programming language theory describing foreign function interfaces (FFI) and multiple language bindings?
- Is there a survey of the semantics of various programming language features?

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for asking before posting, but to be honest, I cannot see any connection of those two questions to [theoretical computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_computer_science).  It is probably possible to vaguely relate your questions to a question in theory of programming languages, but I doubt that doing so would capture what you want to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I'd defer to the programming language experts here (Dave, Neel and others), but my suspicion is that these questions would be out of scope.